# UITableView with sections powered by core data

Tags: ios, core-data

I have the following json file

```
 {
   items = ({“text1” = “lorem ipsum”;},
            {“text2” = “lorem ipsum”;});
   id = 0;
   title = “item0”;
 },
 {
   items = ({“text1” = “lorem ipsum”;},
            {“text2” = “lorem ipsum”;});
   id = 1;
   title = “item1”;
 }
```

i'm using core data for persistence title is the name of the first entity also the section name of the table view i want to populate items array into sections for example section title = "items1" contains 2 items text1 and text2 my problem is with cells how to add that info into cells but with core data.My first attempt was to create an entity with Transformable type for example inside **NSManagedObject** class

```
self.title = [dictionary objectForKey:@"title"];

NSArray *items = [dictionary objectForKey:@"items"];

if ([items isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]])
{
   for (NSDictionary *item in items)
   {
      self.arr = [clip objectForKey:@"text1"];
   }
}
```

any ideas on this topic?

Answer (score 1):

I think you can make use of `NSFetchedResultsController`. Check out the [Apple Docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/CoreData/Reference/NSFetchedResultsController_Class/Reference/Reference.html) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

i'm using the following code for fetch data

```
- (NSFetchedResultsController *)fetchedResultsController
{
    if (!_fetchedResultsController)
    {

        NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
        NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"List" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
        [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];


        NSSortDescriptor *authorDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"test" ascending:YES];
        NSSortDescriptor *titleDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"title" ascending:YES];
        NSArray *sortDescriptors = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:authorDescriptor, titleDescriptor, nil];
        [fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];


        _fetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:self.fetchRequest managedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext sectionNameKeyPath:self.sectionNameKeyPath cacheName:self.cacheName];

        _fetchedResultsController.delegate = self;
        [_fetchedResultsController performFetch:nil];
    }
    return _fetchedResultsController;
}
```

Comment: As of iOS5, you can replace the first three lines with `NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"List"];`